# SQL SELECT items without a character

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    M.* 
FROM 
    (
   SELECT MAX(counter) AS FirstUserDate, imdb_id, language, season, aufloesung, episode
   FROM autofehlerserie
    GROUP BY imdb_id, language
    ) foo 
    JOIN
    autofehlerserie M ON foo.imdb_id = M.imdb_id AND foo.language = M.language
ORDER BY
    foo.FirstUserDate DESC, M.imdb_id, M.aufloesung, cast(M.season as int), cast(M.episode as int)
```

But I want only `SELECT items WHERE marker not = "D"`

Where I have to add this on this `select` query?

Comment: You can use `<>` to represent "does not equal". For example: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE marker <> 'D'`. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: But where I have to add this exactly?

Comment: marker is in the sql "autofehlerserie"

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `WHERE` goes between `FROM` and `GROUP BY`. By the way, your `GROUP BY` is incomplete, and will result in an error in the newer mysql version (unless in compatibility mode), and in unpredictable results in older versions. A `GROUP BY` should contain all selected attributes which are not in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like below :

```
SELECT 
    M.* 
FROM 
    (
   SELECT MAX(counter) AS FirstUserDate, imdb_id, language, season, aufloesung, episode
   FROM autofehlerserie 
   WHERE marker <> 'D'
    GROUP BY imdb_id, language, season, aufloesung, episode
    ) foo 
    JOIN
    autofehlerserie M ON foo.imdb_id = M.imdb_id AND foo.language = M.language and M.marker <> 'D'
ORDER BY
    foo.FirstUserDate DESC, M.imdb_id, M.aufloesung, cast(M.season as int), cast(M.episode as int)
```

Comment: What makes you think that the marker shall only be checked in order to find the sort key? I'd rather think the OP wants it applied to the main query, too.

Comment: But i don't think it needs to add that condition in the main query too, as the OP is using `INNER JOIN` the entire query will produce the result with `marker <> 'D'`

Comment: I see all itms with marker = "D" anyway! This is not the solution!

Comment: No run it well! THX!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might actually want:

```
select m.*
from autofehlerserie m
where not exists (select 1
                  from autofehlerserie m2
                  where m2.imdb_id = m.imdb_id AND m2.language = m.language and
                        m2.marker = 'D'
                 );
```

This returns all rows in your table where there is no other row with the same `imdb_id` and `language` whose `marker` is `'D'`.